# GridView template for a ListView.View

Tags: wpf, xaml

Basically, I want to define a generic GridView template in a separate file so I can use it with multiple ListView. So right now I have this code in XAML:

```
<ListView Height="325" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectNote.Project_Info_Document_File}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewBaseStyle}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- The grid view definition -->                
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

Of course, I also need to keep that binding working to access the properties of the ObservableCollection Project_Info_Document_File

Comment: And **what** is your Issue? Working with Styles? Working with Resources? Working with ControlTemplates?

Comment: I want to re-use the same GridView at different places and with different bindings... without copying all the code. So I was wondering if I could put the GridView definition in another file and use it as a template.

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can define your whole GridView as resource. But your ListView will look everywhere the same independet of what you did bind.

Comment: Move your gridview to App.xaml as resource.

Comment: Nevermind, everything works just fine by doing this <ListView View = "{StaticRessources myGrid}" ...>